# Rewriting constraints of a minimization problem to create an LP

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

[Linear Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfwJ5.png)

I understand that in order to formulate a minimization problem as a linear program, I would have to rewrite the constraints as a linear set of equalities or inequalities. How would I rewrite the L1 norm as a set of linear inequalities/equalities?

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite the L1 norm as a sum of absolute values $\sum_i |y_i|$ and linearize each absolute value.  Here are the two standard ways to reformulate $\sum_i |y_i|\leq1$:

Two variables and one equality:
\begin{align}
y_i^+ - y_i^- &= y_i \\
y_i^+ &\ge 0 \\
y_i^- &\ge 0 \\
\sum_i (y_i^+ + y_i^-) &\le 1
\end{align}

One variable and two inequalities:
\begin{align}
z_i &\ge y_i \\
z_i &\ge -y_i \\
\sum_i z_i &\le 1
\end{align}